# В C# необходимо отредактировать несколько элементов коллекции через LINQ запрос

Tags: c#, linq, коллекции

Язык C#, LINQ, Работа с несколькими элементами коллекции элементов.

Уважаемые коллеги прошу о помощи!
Есть коллекция элементов. Мне необходимо выбрать все элементы с "*Company=Microsoft*" и изменить **в этой же коллекции** на "*Company=12345*" **через LINQ запрос**.

Код:

```
namespace GroupByLinq
{
    class Phone
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>
            {
                new Phone {Name="Lumia 430", Company="Microsoft" },
                new Phone {Name="Mi 5", Company="Xiaomi" },
                new Phone {Name="LG G 3", Company="LG" },
                new Phone {Name="iPhone 5", Company="Apple" },
                new Phone {Name="Lumia 930", Company="Microsoft" },
                new Phone {Name="iPhone 6", Company="Apple" },
                new Phone {Name="Lumia 630", Company="Microsoft" },
                new Phone {Name="LG G 4", Company="LG" }
            };


            //Вот здесь что-то необходимо поправить или присвоения вовсе не должно быть
            phones = phones.SelectMany(x => x.Company == "Microsoft", p => new Phone { Name = p.Name, Company = "Citrus" }).ToList();


            foreach (Phone g in phones)
                Console.WriteLine(g.Company + " / " + g.Name);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для общего понимания ситуации - эта коллекция отображается в GridView (WPF). Данные (в коллекции) обновляются часто(раз в секунду) и порой необходимо изменить значение 10-15 элементов коллекции размером в 500 - 1500 элементов.

Comment: А остальные элементы должны отсутствовать в выходном списке? Или присутствовать, но без изменений?

Comment: присутствовать, но без изменений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq не предназначен для изменения данных, он используется для запросов, поэтому я рекомендую вам воспользоваться обычным циклом, но если очень захотеть, можно написать примерно так:

```
phones = phones
    .Select(p => p.Company == "Microsoft" 
                 ? new Phone { Name = p.Name, Company = "12345" }
                 : p)
    .ToList();
```

Этот подход плох тем, что он не изменяет старые объекты, а создает новые:

а) вы должны учесть что где-то могут остаться ссылки на старые phone, которых теперь нет в новой коллекции;

б) если вы добавите в класс новые свойства - вам придется найти каждый такой запрос и откорректировать его.

Подумайте хорошенько и поймете, что такой вариант будет гораздо лучше (да и, кстати, не сильно многословнее):

```
for (int i = 0; i < phones.Count; ++i)
    if (phones[i].Company == "Microsoft")
        phones[i].Company = "12345";
```

и да, с помощью Linq вы можете выбрать нужные телефоны и итерировать по ним, это тоже корректное решение (объекты остаются те же самые, с помощью Linq выбираем из них нужные):

```
foreach (var phone in phones.Where(p => p.Company == "Microsoft"))
    phone.Company = "12345";
```

А в идеале вам вообще нужно завести отдельный класс для компаний, а в телефоне иметь ссылку на него, тогда смена наименования компании превратится во что-то такое:

```
var company = companies.First(c => c.Name == "Microsoft");
company.Name = "12345";
```

Comment: Замечания хорошие! Попробую реализовать изменение данных в цикле. Предоставленный пример запустил, работает спасибо!

Comment: @ArchiKu, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

`phones.Where(x => x.Company.Equals("Microsoft")).ToList().ForEach(y => y.Company = "12345");`

Comment: не нравится среде ForEach(). Ругается среда. ("Не содержит определения для ForEach ...")

Comment: перед `ForeEach` пропущен `ToList`

Comment: А какая версия c#?

Comment: @MrScapegrace, любая, `ForEach` - это метод класса `List`, а не метод-расширения для `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Андрей ForEach разве работает не с `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Нормально отработал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

простой вариант такой:

```
foreach (Phone g in phones.Where(x => x.Company == "Microsoft")) g.Company = "12345";
```

---

также можно воспользоваться методом расширения:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Update<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> act)
{
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        act(element);                
    }
    return source;
}
```

тогда вызов будет похож на linq:

```
phones.Where(p => p.Company == "Microsoft").Update(p => p.Company = "12345");
```

Стоит помнить, что в обоих вариантах, будут изменены сами значения переменных типа `Phone` в списке. Даже без присвоения результата переменной `phones`

Comment: Второй вариант очень плох - при работе с Linq никто не ожидает что данные будут изменены!

Comment: Согласен. Это, скорее, вариант для тех, кому очень хочется работать с Linq как с SQL. (что тоже не совсем корректно)

Answer (score 1):

just my 5 cents:
если можно MoreLinq использовать, то вот ещё способ

```
phones = phones
  .Pipe(x =>
  {
    if (x.Company.Equals("Microsoft"))
      x.Company = "13245";
  });
```

или как то так:

```
phones = phones
    .Pipe(x => x.Company = x.Company.Equals("Microsoft") ? "12345" : x.Company);
```

Плюс такого подхода в том что над каждым элементом выполняется определённый `Action`, а не создается новый инстанс. Хотя тот же `ForEach()` делает тоже самое только на `List<>` - `Pipe` же можно вызвать на `IEnumerable<>`

Минус подхода - сторонняя библиотека кода (можно без проблем написать свою реализацию `Pipe`-а). Хотя она за частую полезная.

Answer (score 0):

Можно каждый элемент списка вкинуть в анонимный метод:

```
phones=phones.Select(x=>
{
    x.Company=x.Company=="Microsoft"?"Citrus":x.Company;
    return x;
}).ToList();
```